Supply voltage of BLDC motor increases during operation
I need some clarity on an issue I have been encountering with my BLDC motors.I am using 2 integrated driver BLDC motors to drive an RC truck sort of device, they run on 24v.
For the most part it operates fine, however, when the truck is reversing down a hill (the best way i could think of to describe the operation sorry), the supply voltage to the BLDC motors start increasing. This increase in voltage will also increase when the truck is carrying a higher load.
I do not have an in-depth knowledge of why this is happening, but based on the research I did, it seems like since gravity is helping the motors when the truck is reversing down the hill, the motor starts to act as a generator, and a higher load equals more help due to gravity. What i am confused about is why the generated EMF is in the same direction as the voltage being supplied to it ? If it was back EMF shouldn't it oppose the direction of supply voltage and hence reduce the voltage at the motors terminals? What can I do to reduce this increase in voltage since it ends up increasing it enough to trigger the over voltage protection of the driver (i have access to changing the motor min regen and battery min regen values of the driver if that helps). For ease of use, i do not want to be adding anything directly to the motor driver board as well since it is an off the shelf package, but i can add stuff before the motor DC terminals.
Any help would be very much appreciated thanks.

With a BLDC motor the direction of current and torque depends entirely on the way the motor is commutated. While rolling down hill, the drive can coast, accelerate (drawing current), or decelerate (pushing current into the battery). The behavior may be able to be changed in the settings. If it can't be changed or you need the braking, you need to change your power source so that it can absorb that charging current without the voltage rising excessively. For example, maybe a different battery or BMS, can't say without looking at your circuit.
You can also build a circuit that connects a low value resistor across the supply when the voltage rises above a threshold, but this is rarely necessary.
